# Array becomes 'undefined' in forEach inside polymer property observer

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, polymer, undefined

i have a problem that's driving me crazy, i can't understand why this is happening.

I have a custom Polymer element, in this element i set an array with a function, in this element i have a paper-input of which the value is bound to a variable, that variable has an observer and each time that variable changes i run a function that iterates through an array and does some simple checks. Everything works fine until the input value enters the 6-9 range, at which point the array i iterate becomes 'undefined' until i exit that range, i attached an observer to that array and the strange thing is that when the array becomes 'undefined' the observer isn't fired so i guess the actual array isn't changed.

Here is the code

```
    <link rel="import" href="../custom_elements/paper-file-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
<dom-module id="property-editor">

    <style>

        :host{
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .background {
            background: #565456;
            padding: 8pt;
        }

        .full{
            width: 100%;
            height:100%;
        }

        .title{
            color: white;
            font-size: 14pt;
        }

        .prop{
            --paper-input-container-color: white;
            --paper-input-container-focus-color: #e8745c;
            --paper-input-container-input-color: white;
        }

    </style>

    <template style="width:100%; height:100%;">
        <div class="background full">
            <p class="roboto title"><b>PROPRIETA':</b></p>
            <template is="dom-if" if="{{selected}}">
                <div class="altfullright" style="overflow:auto;">
                    <span class="roboto propsec">Tempo:</span>
                    <div style="display:flex; align-items:center;">
                        <paper-input class="prop" style="width:100%; margin-right:8pt;" type="number" label="Da" value="{{from}}" min="0" max="100"></paper-input>
                        <paper-input class="prop" style="width:100%;" type="number" label="A" value="{{to}}" min="0" max="100"></paper-input>
                    </div>
                    <span class="roboto propsec">Posizione:</span>
                    <div style="display:flex; align-items:center;">
                        <paper-input class="prop" style="width:100%; margin-right:8pt;" type="number" label="Left" value="{{left}}" min="0" max="1000"></paper-input>
                        <paper-input class="prop" style="width:100%;" type="number" label="Top" value="{{top}}" min="0" max="1000"></paper-input>
                    </div>
                    <span class="roboto propsec">Generale:</span>
                    <paper-input class="prop" label="Nome" value="{{nome}}"></paper-input>
                    <template is="dom-if" if="{{_or(button, link, text)}}">
                        <paper-input class="prop" label="Testo" value="{{testo}}"></paper-input>
                    </template>
                    <template is="dom-if" if="{{_or(button, link, text)}}">
                        <span class="roboto propsec">Testo:</span>
                        <paper-input class="prop" type="number" label="Dimensione font" min="0" max="100"></paper-input>
                        <paper-color-input allow-alpha class="prop" shape="square" type="hsl" label="Colore font"></paper-color-input>
                        <paper-dropdown-menu class="prop" label="Famiglia font">
                            <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content">
                                <paper-item>Roboto</paper-item>
                                <paper-item>Arial</paper-item>
                                <paper-item>Common Sans</paper-item>
                            </paper-listbox>
                        </paper-dropdown-menu>
                    </template>
                    <span class="roboto propsec">Elemento:</span>
                    <paper-file-input class="prop" label="Sfondo"></paper-file-input>
                    <paper-color-input allow-alpha class="prop" shape="square" type="hsl" label="Colore sfondo"></paper-color-input>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <paper-button raised class="fullwidth white" on-tap="_handleTimestamp">AGGIORNA</paper-button>
                </div>
            </template>
            <template is="dom-if" if="{{!selected}}">
                <div class="altfullright" style="overflow:auto;">
                    <span class="roboto propsec" style="font-size:12pt;">Seleziona un elemento</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <paper-button raised disabled class="fullwidth white">AGGIORNA</paper-button>
                </div>
            </template>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'property-editor',

            properties:{
                nome:{
                    type:String,
                    observer: '_nameChanged'
                },
                selected:{
                    type:Boolean
                },
                testo:{
                    type:String,
                    observer: '_textChanged'
                },
                from:{
                    type:String,
                    observer: '_fromChanged'
                },
                to:{
                    type:String,
                    observer: '_toChanged'
                },
                left:{
                    type:Number,
                    observer: '_leftChanged'
                },
                top:{
                    type:Number,
                    observer: '_topChanged'
                },
                timestamps:{
                    type:Array,
                    observer: '_timeChanged'
                }
            },

            ready: function(){
                this.selected = false;
                var app = this;
                $(document).on('element-selected', function(e){
                    app._handleSelection(e.detail.selected);
                });
            },

            _retrieveOverlayTimestamps: function(){
                var app = this;
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'php/get-timestamp.php',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {'id': app.id},
                    success: function(data){
                        var result = JSON.parse(data);
                        this.timestamps = result;
                    }
                });
            },

            _timeChanged: function(newValue, oldValue){
                console.log("Changed to: "+newValue);
            },

            _or: function(condition, other){
                if(condition || other){
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            },

            _or: function(condition, other, third){
                if(condition || other || third){
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            },

            _fromChanged: function(newValue, oldValue){
                if(newValue < this.to){
                    this.timestamps.forEach(function (elem) {
                        if(newValue >= elem.from && newValue < elem.to){
                            this.timevalid = false;
                        }else if(newValue < elem.from && this.to >= elem.to){
                            this.timevalid = false;
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    this.timevalid = false;
                }
                console.log(this.timevalid);
            },

            _toChanged: function(newValue, oldValue){
                if(this.from < newValue){
                    this.timestamps.forEach(function (elem) {
                        if(newValue < elem.to && newValue >= elem.from){
                            this.timevalid = false;
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    this.timevalid = false;
                }
                console.log(this.timevalid);
            },

            _leftChanged: function(newValue, oldValue){

            },

            _topChanged: function(newValue, oldValue){

            },

            _nameChanged: function(){
                var app = this;
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'php/update-elem.php',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {'property':'overlay_name', 'value':this.nome, 'id':app.id},
                    success: function(){
                        app.fire('element-changed');
                    }
                });
            },

            _textChanged: function(){
                var app = this;
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'php/update-elem.php',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {'property': 'overlay_props', 'value':this.testo, 'id':app.id},
                    success: function(){
                        app.fire('element-changed');
                    }
                });
            },

            _handleTimestamp: function(e){

            },

            _handleSelection: function(index){
                this.selected = true;
                this.timevalid = true;
                this.id = index;
                this._retrieveOverlayTimestamps();
                var app = this;
                $.ajax({
                    url:"php/get-selected.php",
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {'id':index},
                    success: function(data){
                        var result = JSON.parse(data);
                        var element = result[0];
                        var elementstr = $(result[0].type);
                        var tagName = $(elementstr).prop("tagName");
                        app.nome = element.name;
                        app.testo = $(elementstr).html();
                        app.from = element.from;
                        app.to = element.to;
                        app.left = element.x;
                        app.top = element.y;
                        if( tagName == "PAPER-BUTTON" ){
                            if($(element).hasClass('link')){
                                app.link = true;
                                app.button = false;
                                app.image = false;
                                app.text = false;
                            }else{
                                app.link = false;
                                app.button = true;
                                app.image = false;
                                app.text = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>

</dom-module>
```

The error that is thrown when i enter the 6-9 range is this one

```
property-editor.html:183 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
```

Please help, i'm at a loss...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` inside the Ajax call

```
_retrieveOverlayTimestamps: function(){
    var app = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/get-timestamp.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {'id': app.id},
        success: function(data){
            var result = JSON.parse(data);
            this.timestamps = result;   //<-- wrong
        }
    });
}
```

should be

```
app.timestamps = result;
```

Comment: same problem in  _fromChanged and _toChanged with *this* in forEach ... and you should explain why ...

Comment: Yes, sorry, i was looking for the problem inside the observer, but the problem wasn't there, i just found it and came back here to delete the question but i see i was too late, thanks anyways.